# Assigning css class based on html attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a couple of links like the following. My JS method returns either "days" or "week". Based on that return value I want to assign class="active" to one of these where data-period value matches return value. Can someone please suggest 1-2 line JS code to achieve this.

```
 <a href="#" class="hourlyChartPeriod" data-period="days">D</a>
 <a href="#" class="hourlyChartPeriod" data-period="week">W</a>
```

Comment: Post your other JS method, and what you've tried.

Comment: Yes, I am using JQuery. Please suggest.

Comment: Sir tymeJV, because I could not find anything to try on these lines. Are you offended ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite simple when using JQuery:

```
$("a[data-period='" + someMethod() + "']").addClass("active");
```

This of course assumes your method that, "returns either 'days' or 'week'" is called `someMethod`.

Here's a [CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/grinn/pen/Lfmnp).

If you also need to ensure that the other non-matching elements *don't* have the `active` class, remove it from them as well. There's a few ways to do this. This one's nice and clean:

```
$("a[data-period]").removeClass("active");
$("a[data-period='" + someMethod() + "']").addClass("active");
```

...and this is a little further optimized:

```
$("a[data-period]")
    .removeClass("active")
    .filter("a[data-period='" + someMethod() + "']")
    .addClass("active");
```

...because instead of re-selecting from the DOM again, it will reuse those initial `a[data-period]` results. Sadly it still results in removing the class from the elements that will end up having it anyway. But it really doesn't matter if you don't have a *ton* of elements (read: hundreds) that have a `data-period`.

Still, if you want (or need) to be a stickler about it, this is even further optimized:

```
$("a[data-period].active")
    .not($("a[data-period='" + someMethod() + "']").addClass("active"))
    .removeClass("active");
```

...but even harder to read.

Comment: That's how I roll, yo. ;) Thanks.

Comment: Just one more thing .. how can we append an id as well to that selection. I have different links with different ids and I just want to do it for a particular id.

Comment: You mean you want it to end up like `<a href="#" class="hourlyChartPeriod" data-period="days" id="whateverValueYouWant">D</a>`? Just add `.attr("id", "whateverValueYouWant")` after `.addClass("active")`. As a reminder, be careful to make sure your ID's are always unique.

Answer (score 0):

```
jsReturnValue="The Return Value From Your JS Script"

var elems=Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.hourlyChartPeriod'));

var elem=elems.filter(function(e){return e.getAttribute('data-period')===jsReturnValue});

elem.classList.add('newClass')


// or you could use jQuery - which I suspect you might be

  var elems=jQuery('.hourlyChartPeriod');
  elems.filter(function(){
           return $(this).data('period')===jsReturnValue;
  }).addClass('yourNewClass');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please share JQuery version of this as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if(a[i].getAttribute("data-period")) {
            if(a[i].getAttribute("data-period") == <YOUR_VALUE>)
                a[i].classList.add("active");
        }
    }
</script>
```

And to remove the class you use: .classList.remove("active");

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var collection = document.getElementsByClassName("hourlyChartPeriod"),
    attr = '';
for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    attr = collection[i].getAttribute("data-period");

    switch (attr) {
        case "days":
            collection[i].style.color = "red";
            break;
        case "week":
            collection[i].style.color = "green";
            break;
        default:
            continue;
    } 
}
```

[Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kvxy7etk/)

---

And here is how you can do it with jQuery:

```
$('.hourlyChartPeriod').each(function() {

    switch ($(this).attr('data-period')) {
        case "days":
            $(this).addClass('red');
            break;
        case "week":
            $(this).addClass('green');
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

});
```

[Another JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69mtfxsj/)

You could even just append the `data-period` name as the CSS class name by changing

```
$(this).addClass('red'); // change this
$(this).addClass($(this).attr('data-period')); // to this
```

Although if you can, it would be simpler just to add the class name to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a very easy way to do that without jQuery:

```
var active = document.querySelectorAll('[data-period="' + return_value + '"]');

for (var i = 0; i < active.length; i++) {
  active[i].classList.add('active');
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pascalockert/cnfoe2yc/)